# Change font of the floating label EditText and TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout, material-components

Someone tried to change the font of the floating label? I changed the source of EditText but the font of the floating label did not change, I am very grateful to those who help me

Code:

```
               <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tilTextoDescricao"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tilValorUnidade"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etTextoDescricao"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:hint="Descrição"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:inputType="text" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

----------------- 

   etTextoDescricao= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTextoDescricao);
  etTextoDescricao.setTypeface(CustomTypeface.getTypefaceMediumDefault(this));
```

[image]

Answer (score 36):

As of `Design Library v23`, you can use [`TextInputLayout#setTypeface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#settypeface).

This will set the typeface on both the expanded and floating hint.

Here is the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175733) where it was discussed on [b.android.com](http://b.android.com).

**EDIT:** The error view typeface was not being set, but is now [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227803) in `v25.1.0`.

Comment: I did this and it worked for everything but the error view. I think the textappearance overwrites it, so that's probably a bug of some sort. To target the error view in specific, you can use the android-given ID to reference it like this:
**((TextView)inputLayout.findViewById(R.id.textinput_error)).setTypeface(customFont);**

Comment: @JustinLiu Your issue was fixed in Support Library v25.1.0 - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227803

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, you'll have to use reflection to handle this.

The floating label is drawn by `CollapsingTextHelper`, which is an internal, package-private class and isn't setup to handle spans. So, using something like a custom `TypefaceSpan` won't work in this case.

Because this uses reflection, it isn't guaranteed to work in the future.

**Implementation**

```
final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_custom_font.ttf");
final TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTextInputLayout);
til.getEditText().setTypeface(tf);
try {
    // Retrieve the CollapsingTextHelper Field
    final Field cthf = til.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
    cthf.setAccessible(true);

    // Retrieve an instance of CollapsingTextHelper and its TextPaint
    final Object cth = cthf.get(til);
    final Field tpf = cth.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
    tpf.setAccessible(true);

    // Apply your Typeface to the CollapsingTextHelper TextPaint
    ((TextPaint) tpf.get(cth)).setTypeface(tf);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
    // Nothing to do
}
```

**Error view**

If you needed to change the font of the error, you could do one of two things:

1. Use Reflection grab the error `TextView` and apply the `Typeface` much like before
2. Use a custom span. Unlike the floating label, the error view used by `TextInputLayout` is just a `TextView`, so it's able to handle spans.

**Using reflection**

```
final Field errorField = til.getClass().getDeclaredField("mErrorView");
errorField.setAccessible(true);
((TextView) errorField.get(til)).setTypeface(tf);
```

**Using a custom span**

```
final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Error");
ss.setSpan(new FontSpan(tf), 0, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
til.setError(ss);

private static final class FontSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {

    private final Typeface mNewFont;

    private FontSpan(Typeface newFont) {
        mNewFont = newFont;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setTypeface(mNewFont);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.setTypeface(mNewFont);
    }

}
```

**Results**

[image: results]

The font I'm using is [Smoothie Shoppe](http://www.dafont.com/smoothie-shoppe.font).

Comment: How i can use this in single class, my issue is this i having so many layout then all the time i have to use this code in all the classes that's why i am asking.Is it possible?

Comment: Terrible that you have to do it this way, but it'll works for now.
However, ((TextView) errorField.get(til)) return null for me :(

Comment: It seems that you can now use `setTypeface(Typeface typeface)` on the TextInputLayout. :)

Comment: I want to change only floating label font. Is it possible?

Answer (score 21):

I'm using new [`MaterialComponents`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) theme and none of the answers helped me.

Had to play with styles and themes on my own. Will post a chunk of styles here in case somebody faces the same issue.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
  ...
  <item name="textInputStyle">@style/CustomFontTextInputLayout</item>
</style>  

<!-- region TextInputLayout & TextInputEditText styles -->
<style name="TextInputLayout.OutlineBox.CustomFont" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
  <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
  <item name="editTextStyle">@style/TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomFontTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
  <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHintText</item>
  <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHelperText</item>
  <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutErrorText</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHintText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHelperText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.HelperText">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
</style>
<!-- endregion -->
```

Then in xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/TextInputLayout.OutlineBox.CustomFont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Did not work for me for hint in password fields, because of issue described [here](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/186#issuecomment-138376055). Had to set typeface in the code.

Comment: it works for font change, but the form box style was gone.

Answer (score 9):

i just found a simple solution and it's worked for me:

in this way you can set the typeface to hint of any edit text:

in layout.xml :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/username"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and in java class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Typeface font_yekan= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/byekan.ttf");
        textInputLayout= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input1);
    textInputLayout.setTypeface(font_yekan);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Weird, this should have worked for me. I used a custom text input layout and only changed the typeface while initializing using the setTypeface() and still the error view has the older one. This is strange since it's there in the code that error view also takes typeface in the setTypeface(). Any clue what I might be missing?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a custom class implementation for [adneal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30767869/412466).

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initFont(context);
    }

    private void initFont(Context context) {
        final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                context.getAssets(), "fonts/YOUR_CUSTOM_FONT.ttf");

        EditText editText = getEditText();
        if (editText != null) {
            editText.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
        try {
            // Retrieve the CollapsingTextHelper Field
            final Field cthf = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
            cthf.setAccessible(true);

            // Retrieve an instance of CollapsingTextHelper and its TextPaint
            final Object cth = cthf.get(this);
            final Field tpf = cth.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
            tpf.setAccessible(true);

            // Apply your Typeface to the CollapsingTextHelper TextPaint
            ((TextPaint) tpf.get(cth)).setTypeface(typeface);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // Nothing to do
        }
    }
}
```

In your XML files now you need to use `CustomTextInputLayout` instead of `TextInputLayout` and it will work out of the box.

```
<your.package.CustomTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

Thanks [adneal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420015/adneal) for the answer.

Comment: Not worked with com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Answer (score 5):

```
final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "your_custom_font.ttf");
final TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourTextInputLayout);
til.getEditText().setTypeface(tf);
til.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Please explain something about your approach

Comment: @etalon11,A textview or edit text will be wrapped inside a `TextInputLayout` and applying a type face for the `TextInputLayout` will eventually apply the attributes to it children. I believe that this will work.

Comment: TextInputLayout member mEditText which getEditText() returns is different from mErrorView which is a TextView. This shouldn't working, please check.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler way,

Create a new directory in your 'res' folder named 'font' and put a font in there. Then open your 'styles' file and create a new style :

```
<style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
    </style>
```

You can add more properties as well, such as textColor, textSize etc..

Then in your XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/customfontstyle"
       >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_phone_number"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number_label"

            android:inputType="number"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I checked it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Use can use style.xml like below:

Style file:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutErrorStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/iran_sans_medium</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iran_sans_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHintStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/iran_sans_medium</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iran_sans_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHelperStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.HelperText">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/iran_sans_medium</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iran_sans_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutOutlinedBoxStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHelperStyle</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutErrorStyle</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHintStyle</item>
</style>
```

Layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:hint="@string/cardname_hint"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            card_view:helperText="@string/cardname_helper"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutOutlinedBoxStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iran_sans_medium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this, I found this way, using the support library:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);
```

and set this typeface to yout TextInpuLayout.

For me works like charm, I hope it helps others =]

Source: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

fixing a problem in @adneal answer:
if setErrorEnabled is not set true, mErrorView would be null and if you set it false at any point the font would change back to default.
so to fix it:

in you custom TextInputLayout override setErrorEnabled

```
@Override
public void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled) {

    super.setErrorEnabled(enabled);

    if (enabled) {

        try {

            Field cthf = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mErrorView");
            cthf.setAccessible(true);

            TextView error = (TextView) cthf.get(this);

            if (error != null)
                error.setTypeface(tf);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i achieve this

```
edit_login_emailOrPhone.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
            {
                textInputLayout_login_emailOrPhone.setTypeface(APSApplication.getInstance().getFonts().getTypefaceSemiBold());
            }else
            {
                textInputLayout_login_emailOrPhone.setTypeface(APSApplication.getInstance().getFonts().getTypefaceRegular());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you too met an exotic requirement to set custom font ONLY to the floating label, and anything else didn't work for you as well, try this. This worked for me, at least for material lib ver. 1.3.0-alpha03.

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
fun setHintFontFamily(view: TextInputLayout, fontRes: Int) {
    val font = ResourcesCompat.getFont(view.context, fontRes)!!

    try {
        val collapsingTextHelperField =
            view::class.java.getDeclaredField("collapsingTextHelper").apply {
                isAccessible = true
            }
        val collapsingTextHelper = collapsingTextHelperField.get(view) as CollapsingTextHelper

        collapsingTextHelper.collapsedTypeface = font
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

First we get the `CollapsingTextHelper` as in some other answers, but then we use its property `collapsedTypeface` that seems to do exactly what we need -- apply a font only to the floating label. Please note that this property's visibility is restricted to library group (that's why I used  `@SuppressLint`). So the implementation details might change in the future.