# Font for CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to set the font for a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?
I'm using Calligraphy but my default font is not applied.

I think the problem is the `CollapsingTextHelper` class is using `Canvas.drawText()` instead of a `TextView`.

How can I change the default font that is used for `Canvas.drawText()`?

Comment: You'll have to use Reflection. [I described how to do it with the `TextInputLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30767869/420015), but the steps should be the same for the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: @lukas1994 can you give your source?

Comment: @lukas1994 already done, thanks for this question and answer

Answer (score 19):

Since one of the latest API updates, the Support Design Package has been updated and now it's possible to set the font of the collapsing title text.

Use [`setCollapsedTitleTypeFace(Typeface typeface)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setCollapsedTitleTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)) and [`setExpandedTitleTypeFace(Typeface typeface)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setExpandedTitleTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)) to set your custom font.

Comment: Has anyone got this to work? Seems like it's doing nothing.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! You need to use callygraphy's `TypefaceUtils.load()` to load a typeface for this...

Comment: @RED_ It was doing nothing also for me. Set **setCollapsedTitleTypeFace** after setting the title worked for me

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. In fact, by default, the font of the title when it's collapsed is different than the one when it's not.

So, in order to change this, for example, you can do as such:

**styles file**

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Collapsed"
    parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

**layout file**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Collapsed">
    ...
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Similar thing can be done for the style of when it's not collapsed ("expandedTitleTextAppearance") .

Comment: I did exactly this and it didn't help :/ I can see the font changed in the layout editor, but not at runtime.

Comment: @milosmns If you can make a sample project with this issue, report it here as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues

Comment: I actually managed to apply the font at runtime using some of the answers below. Just a fun fact, that way it works.

Comment: @milosmns So changing it programmatically works, but not via XML ? I suggest to report about it. It used to work fine.

Comment: I'll need to verify this in a sample project, but that's right.

Answer (score 2):

You can trick by wrapping the widget class. Change the `TypeFace` when widget attached to window.

**Tip:** [`Calligraphy`](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library included helper class for `TypeFace`. You can generate `TypeFace` based on `AssetManager` and path to font in assets directory.

For example, I will apply custom font for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` class:

```
class CollapsingToolbarLayoutWrapper : CollapsingToolbarLayout {
    
    // Required constructors
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        try {
            val applicationContext = this.context.applicationContext
            val assetManager = applicationContext.assets
            val fontBold = applicationContext.getString(R.string.font_default_bold)
            this.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(TypefaceUtils.load(assetManager, fontBold))
            this.setExpandedTitleTypeface(TypefaceUtils.load(assetManager, fontBold))
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            // Maybe exceptions from typeface, like missing font in assets, for font is not accept,...
        }
    }

}
```

And in layout xml file, use `CollapsingToolbarLayoutWrapper` instead:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <!-- ... -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <!-- ... -->
        <....CollapsingToolbarLayoutWrapper
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
          app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
          
          <!-- (optional) If you need to change title text size for collapsed/expanded states, can change attributes app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance, app:expandedTitleTextAppearance -->
          app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Widget.Style.Toolbar.TextAppearance.Title"
          app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Widget.Style.Toolbar.TextAppearance.Title.Expanded"

          app:expandedTitleGravity="start|bottom"
          app:expandedTitleMarginStart="32dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
                <!-- ... -->
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </....CollapsingToolbarLayoutWrapper>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text appearance of the title of a CollapsingToolbarLayout as follows:

1) Make sure that you are using `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` in your build.gradle dependencies.

2) Use expandedTitleTextAppearance like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/myPrimaryColor"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/HeaderTitleStyle">
```

3) Define the HeaderTitleStyle in your styles file:

```
<style name="HeaderTitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How does this answer the original question, about setting a custom font?

Comment: this does not  help setting custom font

Answer (score 0):

First step is to pick a font that you want to use.

Second create a Fonts folder in your assets directory and copy your font there.

Xml file

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
<!-- Your content-->
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Java File

```
 private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString("Toolbar name");
                    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                            "res/font/frederickathegreatregular.ttf");
                    collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(tf);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom font with the Android App Bar Layout and Collapsing Toolbar Layouts

Inside of CoordinatorLayout below code:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_color_palette"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="28dp"

            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.CollapsingToolbar.Collapsed"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/sample1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="@string/toolbar_title"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_with_icons"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer_white"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.App.CollapsingToolbar.Expanded" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5">
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/rosarivo</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rosarivo</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.App.CollapsingToolbar.Collapsed" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/rosarivo</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rosarivo</item>
    </style>
```

Output:
[image]