# How to change font style of label in TextInputLayout wrapping with EditText android

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputLayout wraps with EditText and i I am using custom fonts. I am able to set typeface on edittext and its working but same font is not working for TextInputLayout Label. How to set font type on TextInputLayout Label?

I have already tried [Change font of the floating label EditText and TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765287/change-font-of-the-floating-label-edittext-and-textinputlayout)
But not working at all.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30767869/2571277

Answer (score 2):

As of `Design Library v23`, you can use [`TextInputLayout#setTypeface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)).

This will set the typeface on both the expanded and floating hint.

[Feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175733) where it was discussed on b.android.com.

Comment: How about from XML? and Does it work only with Android Fonts? Or any fonts?

Comment: I haven't tried, but the linked docs don't list an XML attribute for `typeface`. It will work with any font you can read into an Android `Typeface` object. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

Comment: For some reason its only working for TextInputEditText with android:inputType="textPassword".