# Is it possible to have different font for floating text and hint text of InputTextLayout

Tags: android, android-fonts

Currently, I would like to have a bold effect on my floating text of `InputTextLayout`. Here's what I'm doing

```
this.usernameTextInputLayout.setTypeface(Utils.ROBOTO_BOLD_TYPE_FACE);
```

It works as expected. The floating text (Username) has became bold.

[image]

However, this will create another undesired effect for me. The hint text will become bold as well.

[image]

You can compare the above 2 images. Please take note, for comparison purpose, I just leave `passwordTextInputLayout` as it is.

Is it possible to have different fonts, for floating text and hint text of `InputTextLayout`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I'm pretty sure it would take reflection to do it. I've recently written a couple of custom `TextInputLayout` subclasses, and, off the top of my head, I can't think of a way to do it without reflection. If that's acceptable, I can probably put something together.

Comment: I had tried reflection technique in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30767869/72437 It will affect hint text as well.

Comment: Hmm, I'm relatively confident that it can be done. Gimme a little bit to do some tests. I'll let ya know.

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it, barring any unforeseen side effects. I can post an answer, if you'd like, so you can test it with your setup.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Can you kindly post your finding as answer? I will test it out later time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you know, `TextInputLayout` uses a private helper class to handle the hint text stylings and animations. This class - `CollapsingTextHelper` - maintains separate typefaces for its *collapsed* and *expanded* states. We just need to set the right one, which we'll do using reflection.

I usually package these kinds of functionalities into custom subclasses, so I'll do the same here. If you don't want to use a subclass, the reflection stuff could be easily pulled into some simple methods you can put in your `Activity` or utility class.

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    private Object collapsingTextHelper;
    private Method setCollapsedTypefaceMethod;
    private Method setExpandedTypefaceMethod;

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            Field cthField = TextInputLayout.class
                .getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
            cthField.setAccessible(true);
            collapsingTextHelper = cthField.get(this);

            setCollapsedTypefaceMethod = collapsingTextHelper
                .getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setCollapsedTypeface", Typeface.class);
            setCollapsedTypefaceMethod.setAccessible(true);

            setExpandedTypefaceMethod = collapsingTextHelper
                .getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setExpandedTypeface", Typeface.class);
            setExpandedTypefaceMethod.setAccessible(true);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            collapsingTextHelper = null;
            setCollapsedTypefaceMethod = null;
            setExpandedTypefaceMethod = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setCollapsedTypeface(Typeface typeface) {
        if (collapsingTextHelper == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            setCollapsedTypefaceMethod.invoke(collapsingTextHelper, typeface);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setExpandedTypeface(Typeface typeface) {
        if (collapsingTextHelper == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            setExpandedTypefaceMethod.invoke(collapsingTextHelper, typeface);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhat counterintuitively, `TextInputLayout`'s *collapsed* state is when the hint is the floating label above the `EditText`. Its *expanded* state is when the hint is in the "normal" position, inside the `EditText`. Methods to set the typeface for both states are given above.

This is a drop-in replacement for `TextInputLayout`, and you can use it in your layouts just as you would that. For example:

```
<com.mycompany.myapp.CustomTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/username_til"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:hint="Username" />

</com.mycompany.myapp.CustomTextInputLayout>
```

In your code, to set the typeface of the floating text hint:

```
CustomTextInputLayout usernameTextInputLayout =
    (CustomTextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.username_til);

usernameTextInputLayout.setCollapsedTypeface(Utils.ROBOTO_BOLD_TYPE_FACE);
```

---

<sup>The `CollapsingTextHelper` methods used above were added in version 23.1.0 of the support library. If you're using a previous version, or you're getting a `NoSuchMethodException` for some other reason, [the original version of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40201827/1) that directly sets the typeface fields should work, no matter the version.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the code. I realize hint text doesn't follow the font in `EditText`. However, by using reflection on `mExpandedTypeface`, I'm able to change hint text's font too.

Comment: Oh, doesn't it? I'll have to have a look at the source again. I probably had both set to the same in my theme, and I'd just assumed the one was set from the other. Thanks for the info! I'll update the answer with a correction after review the code again to be sure what's going on there. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: I just had a dig through the latest source, and the hint typeface still seems to be set from the `EditText`'s, but the style is restricted to `NORMAL`. I realized, though, that you might be setting the `EditText`'s typeface at runtime, after inflation, in which case, yeah, you're right; the `TextInputLayout` won't change its typeface. It only initializes that itself when the `EditText` is first added to it. After that, it won't react to changes you make on the `EditText`. It's the same for the hint string, color, etc.

Comment: Anyhoo, I did happen upon a couple of newer methods in `CollapsingTextHelper` that might simplify your code a bit, since you're setting both typefaces: `setCollapsedTypeface()` and `setExpandedTypeface()`. We still need to use reflection to get them, but it's a simple `invoke()` call to use them, and they call `recalculate()` themselves, so we can drop that bit. I've updated the answer to use them. If you wanna give 'em a try, lemme know if you've any problems, and I'll rollback the answer. I don't think you will, though, as long as you're using at least version 23.4.0 of the support library.

Comment: Im having NoSuchMethodException starting here: 

```setCollapsedTypefaceMethod = collapsingTextHelper
                .getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setCollapsedTypeface", Typeface.class);```

Would be nice to be have a different floating label font and hint font.
Please help.

Comment: @ekouChiq You're probably using an older version of the support library. I'm not sure exactly which version added those methods, but I'll figure it out here in a little while. For now, update to the newest version you can, if possible.

Comment: @ekouChiq  If you can't update, [the original version of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40201827/1) should work for you.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm actually using v.25.2.0... The original version works for me... Thank you.

Comment: @ekouChiq Hmm, I just found that those methods were added in version 23.1.0, so 25.2.0 should work. Weird. Anyhoo, I'll do some more checks, and add a note to my answer about that. Thanks for reminding me. I'd meant to do that after I refactored for those methods, and completely forgot. Glad I had something worked for ya, at any rate. Cheers!

Comment: How can i call these methods within the same class problematically instead of calling them from activity.

Comment: @UsmanRana I'm not sure what you're asking. If you mean you want to immediately set those typefaces directly in `CustomTextInputLayout`, then you can call `setCollapsedTypeface()` and `setExpandedTypeface()` right after the `init()` call in the third constructor.

Comment: that's exactly what i want, but calling in init didn't work work me. I had to call them in my activity or BindingUtils. How to set immediately?

Comment: @UsmanRana Do it in `onFinishInflate()` instead. It should be done setting itself up by then.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. , this was exactly that i asked for.

Comment: @UsmanRana No problem. Yeah, it's been a while since I played with `TextInputLayout`. I forgot that it initially sets those typefaces internally when the `EditText` gets added, and that happens well after the constructor runs. Glad it worked. Cheers!

Comment: Field cthField = TextInputLayout.class
                .getDeclaredField("collapsingTextHelper"); worked for me