# TextInputLayout floating label custom font and edittext custom font

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have layout like this -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

As per our UI design document, we need to have different custom font for Floating label and Edittext.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font

Comment: Basically it will set custom font for TextView or EditText. I want set custom font for Floating Label of TextInputLayout.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765287/change-font-of-the-floating-label-edittext-and-textinputlayout

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by this way,

As of `Design Library v23`, you can use [`TextInputLayout#setTypeface()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3l38.png).

This will set the typeface on both the expanded and floating hint.

**Using a custom span**

```
final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Error");
ss.setSpan(new FontSpan(tf), 0, ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
til.setError(ss);

private static final class FontSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {

    private final Typeface mNewFont;

    private FontSpan(Typeface newFont) {
        mNewFont = newFont;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setTypeface(mNewFont);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.setTypeface(mNewFont);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Please don't just copy from other users' answers. If you think another another post has the solution(s), vote it as a duplicate of that post.

Comment: i know that sir, but this question is some what different.

Comment: Really? Even though you think a straight copy-paste from answers there is the solution? By "there", I mean [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765287/change-font-of-the-floating-label-edittext-and-textinputlayout), the link for which you just edited out of your answer.

Comment: i know i have edied but have given solution to questioner and provided combined solution.

Comment: I don't see where OP is asking about the error text. Did you even read the code you plagiarized? It is plagiarism now, since you've removed any sort of attribution.

Comment: i know that if user want to customize his font than it can be done by this way in TextInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

For custom fonts in EditText you can use following class:

```
public class CustomEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

public CustomEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs);
}

public CustomEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);

}

public CustomEditText (Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

Typeface myTypeface;

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CustomTextView);
        String fontName = "Orkney Medium.otf";
        if (fontName != null && !isInEditMode()) {
            myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    fontName);

        }
        setTypeface(myTypeface);
        a.recycle();
    }


}
```

}

**XML Code :**

```
  <com.utils.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_first_name_register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

For TextInputLayout custom classes does not work in all cases, But you can do something like this for optimized solution.

**Put this in your Java Class :**

```
 public static void setTextInputLayoutTypeFace(Context mContext, TextInputLayout... textInputLayout) {
    for (TextInputLayout til : textInputLayout) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Orkney Regular.otf");
        til.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

}
```

**Call the above method using :**

```
setTextInputLayoutTypeFace(mContext, tlFirstNameRegister, tlLastNameRegister,
            tlUsernameRegister, tlEmailIdRegister, tlDateOfBirthRegister, tlMobileRegister, tlPasswordRegister,
            tlConfPasswordRegister);
```

Its not the best solution. But it will work.