# create typeface from font resource id

Tags: android, fonts, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-typeface

I have tried using `Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/myfont.ttf"));`

I know font directory should be in assets but in my case, I have an existing font resource directory so I thought asset manager will read from font resource directory but I was wrong. I am creating Typeface to set custom font for collapsingToolbarLayout.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765287/change-font-of-the-floating-label-edittext-and-textinputlayout/30767869#30767869) but it requires me to keep font in assets

Comment: I suggest you to follow [this very good tutorial](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library). More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

This worked

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.app_font);
```

Found this in the tutorial link by @Eselfar

Comment: Firstly, when I posted this, I didn't know it would help so many people. Secondly, unanswered questions keep lying stale on SO so it's a good practice to tell the community what solved your problem and thus close your question. Finally, the link may break in future so posting the relevant line from a long article is always helpful and obviously not a means of scoring points. *This is a community not a competition*, so stop assuming things and do something to help people.

Comment: I think I have explained myself quite clearly even though I didn't need to. If you are not satisfied with it, you can raise a question on meta and the mods  will tell whats the correct behaviour. But before that read community guidelines of QnA and tell them what guidline you think I am violating. Comment section isn't for word war.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to create the `TypeFace` from a font stored in assets folder,

[image]

you don´t need to define the directory, just the name of the font:

```
Typeface typeface =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"app_font.ttf");
```

---

You can create the Typeface using the resource id of the font stored into the `/font` folder like this :

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.app_font);
```

your font must be stored into the `/font` directory

[image]

Comment: OP was asking about fonts in the res folder, not assets

Comment: for c#
Typeface type = Resources.GetFont(Resource.Font.app_font);