# Android mancj.MaterialSearchBar: Using reflection to override and change some API layout and widgets, font-family, boldness and padding

Tags: android, android-widget, android-xml, android-library

I'm using https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar to set a search bar with a menu burger. **I can't change of API.**

Here is what I obtained:

[image]

## Questions

How to...:

1. Reduce the padding-left of the text?
2. Change the font-family of the latter?
3. Finally, disable boldness?

NB: these questions are completed by some others in the next section, ***According to the documentation***.

## According to the documentation

`mt_aBCD` are the XML attributes that allow us to customize the search bar. However, the above ones don't exist. Their Java equivalent (`setABCD` neither).

By the way, note that there isn't a lot of Github activity for this API. I can't replace the latter with another one. What solution would you give me?

1. Should I change something in this API (is it authorized and legal)? (how?)
2. Could I override the style? etc. (how?)
3. Other?

## My implementation

I edited my build file, then I simply added the search bar in my XML layout:

```
    <com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
    android:id="@+id/material_search_bar"
    style="@style/MaterialSearchBarLight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
    app:mt_navIconEnabled="true"
    app:mt_placeholder="@string/search_placeholder" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **First moment:**

this library not support font-familly. This question exists in the [github](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/issues) block "**ISSUE**"

[image]

---

### Second moment:

padding for you text not support like and "disable boldness"

---

### But you can solve your problems with reflection

### this is not the best solution but it works

```
    searchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    try {
        final Field placeHolder = searchBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("placeHolder");
        placeHolder.setAccessible(true);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) placeHolder.get(searchBar);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);

        // fix trouble number 1 paddingLeft
        textView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

        //fix trouble number 2 font-family and number 3 Finally, disable boldness?
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), getString(R.string.roboto_medium));
        //<string name="roboto_medium">fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf</string>
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);

        textView.setText("Hello World!");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Burger menu have size 48dp it is not margins(DeclaredField = navIcon)
[image]

---

### Last variant

copy this library in you project and edited all you want .
you can do it because this library used [license MIT](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/blob/master/LICENSE)
*most importantly specify the original author*

Comment: Tahnk you very much for help! I have 2 questions: a) How could I use my own `R.font.` families instead of `Typeface.SANS_SERIF`? and b) The padding set with `textView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);` doesn't delete the space between the burger menu and the `TextView`: maybe it's the burger menu that owns some `padding-right`: how could I be sure of that and how could I find the correspondig `DeclaredField` to set its `padding-right` to 0?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler i fixed my answer check it out.

Comment: I edited the title of my question to be more pertinent and indexable by search engines.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to replace `            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getAssets(), "fonts/newscycle_regular.ttf");` with something directly using `R.font.`?

Comment: NB: `Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), R.font.XYZ);` is an alternative to your call `Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getAssets(), "fonts/newscycle_regular.ttf");` :-). Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688026/create-typeface-from-font-resource-id

Comment: yes you can or [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562408/set-specific-font-in-a-styles-xml/52447866#52447866)

Comment: I tested your code with a longer text, and it is cut very sooner than being close to the magnifying glass icon. Is it a problem of width of the text view? I tried to set it, but didn't seem to work. Do you have any idea thus? Is it the icon?

Comment: I think yes, the last picture in my answer shows areas of all fields and icons.

Comment: It wasn't a problem of width. The issue was due to a too long sentence, badly cut by this API :-). Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I solved same thing with this:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), R.font.XXX);
placeHolder = findViewById(R.id.mt_placeholder);
placeHolder.setTypeface(typeface);
```