# How to change font from a kotlin project?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to change the font from a specific EditText in the MainActivity, but I'm getting the following error :

java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found font/af.ttf

the code :

```
val texto: EditText = findViewById(R.id.texto)
        var face = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "font/af.ttf")
        texto.typeface = face
```

How do I solve this?

[image: * the font is in a folder called font in the res folder. *]

Comment: That's not an asset, it's a resource. An asset is in your assets folder. Does this answer your question? [create typeface from font resource id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688026/create-typeface-from-font-resource-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your fonts to the assets directory

From the docs

```
   /**
     * @param mgr  The application's asset manager
     * @param path The file name of the font data in the assets directory
     * @return The new typeface.
     */
    public static Typeface createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path)
```

[image]

Comment: I dont have a assets folder

Comment: You can create via right-click to the main package then new/directory

Comment: it worked, thanks!