# val cannot be reassigned while using var for declaration

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my code, it's very strange, I'm using var for the declaration

```
lateinit var ln_onvan: TextInputLayout
lateinit var typeface: Typeface

typeface = Func.getTypeface(this)
ln_onvan=findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.ln_onvan)

///on this line I get this error
ln_onvan.typeface=typeface;
```

I don't understand it, could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `.typeface` this is not reassignable

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes it's , I just edit my post

Comment: which line is causing the issue? Are you shadowing any variables with function arguments (which are implicitly `final`)?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: "yes it is" no it's not

Comment: Are you sure that the error is not at this line: `ln_onvan=findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.ln_onvan)`?

Answer (score 1):

ln_onvan.typeface does not refer to your local variable typeface.
You should refer to this existing question to change typeface of your TextInputLayout : [Change font of the floating label EditText and TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765287/change-font-of-the-floating-label-edittext-and-textinputlayout)